# help with sql query join?

Tags: sql, join, count

i have two tables with type(type,playerid) and player(playerid,date)
i have to find out for each year how many man of the match awards were won by which type of player ?

eg the table should be like

```
year type      noofawards
2011 batsmen       3
2011 bowler        5
2010 batsmen       2
```

i can get the total number of awards won each year but cannot segregate them on type so what i get is

```
year noofawards
2011     3 


select year , count(year) as "Number of awards"
from
(
select to_char(p.date,'YYYY') as year 
from player p, type t
where p.playerid = t.playerid
)
group by year
order by year;
```

what should i do?

Comment: type(type,playerid) and player(playerid,date) ... then where do we find man of the match record from?

Comment: You can group by (or "segregate" by) more than one field.  Explore the "group by" syntax options.

Comment: sorry to get the number of awards we have to count the number of bowlers,batsmen etc

Comment: What is missing here is the Awards table itself. You have a Player Type table and a Player/Year table. The aggregation based on the information provided provides you the different types of players you had per year. (Maybe I'm reading into this too deep.)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the following:

```
select to_char(p.date,'YYYY') as year
     , type
     , count(*)
from player p, type t
where p.playerid = t.playerid
group by 1,2;
```

Comment: i need to just arrange them year wise this is where i was having my problems. i cannot count the number of types

Comment: This still does not give me a total no of types....

The result i get is

2011 Batsmen 1
2011 Batsmen 1

Wheras i need

2011 Batsmen 2

Comment: My alias of Year and ordinal GROUP BY may present a challenge depending on the RDBMS used. ypercube's repsonse with the GROUP BY using the column/alias reference is more robust.

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

```
GROUP BY year
       , type
```

---

- Most database systems have a function (`YEAR()` or similar name) to extract year from a date.
- Having field or table names which are reserved, like `date` is not a good idea.
- You should also try learning the `JOIN` syntax rather the implicit join with `WHERE`.

Something like:

```
SELECT YEAR(p.date) AS awardYear
     , t.type
     , COUNT(*) AS "Number of awards"
FROM player p
  JOIN type t
    ON p.playerid = t.playerid
GROUP BY awardYear
       , t.type
ORDER BY awardYear
       , t.type ;
```

Comment: This still does not give me a total no of types....

The result i get is

2011 Batsmen 1
2011 Batsmen 1

Wheras i need

2011 Batsmen 2

Comment: i am able to extract the year.... just having a problem with getting the subquery to work which adds all the types together under one category....

Like total no. of batsmen who won the awad in 2011 and total no of bowlers who won it in 2011 and so on....

Comment: @user779214: Have you tried this query? What result does it give you? Can you also edit your question and add at the end a small sample of your tables data?

Answer (score 1):

Since this screams of homework, i will just give hints.

you don't need to use an subqueries and you need to actually select the Type column at some point in your query.

Comment: Then I give you an upvote for honesty. 

To many students come here looking for answers and not help.  Its nice to see someone who actually wants to understand what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT year,
       type,
       COUNT(*) as number
FROM (
       SELECT type,
              to_char(player.date,'YYYY') as year
       FROM player
       NATURAL JOIN type
     ) AS T
GROUP BY year,
         type
```